# sub-query and INTERSECT

Tags: sql, oracle, intersection

I am trying to select name,zip and phone numbers of instructors who teach their students that live in same zipcode as the instructor

first I select zip where student and instructor have the same ZIP

```
SELECT ZIP 
FROM STUDENT
INTERSECT
SELECT ZIP
FROM INSTRUCTOR;
```

and it gives me what I want

```
ZIP 
-----
10025
```

so how do I now select first name , last name and phone from the ZIP that I have already selected ? How could I combine them ?

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,PHONE
FROM INSTRUCTOR w, STUDENT s
WHERE w.STUDENT_ID = w.STUDENT_ID
GROUP BY FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,PHONE
HAVING COUNT(*) =
(SELECT ZIP
FROM
(SELECT ZIP 
FROM STUDENT
INTERSECT
SELECT ZIP
FROM INSTRUCTOR));
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results?  You say the right result is a zip, and yet I'm thinking either a list of instructors (all/any of whose students are in the same zip code) or instructor/student pairs (in the same zip code).  Sample data and results is usually the least ambiguous way to describe results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to select Instructors details and Students details? If so try

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,PHONE 
FROM
    (
    SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,PHONE,ZIP
    FROM INSTRUCTOR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,PHONE ,ZIP
    FROM STUDENT
    ) 
Derived
 WHERE ZIP IN (SELECT ZIP FROM STUDENT 
               INTERSECT
               SELECT ZIP
               FROM INSTRUCTOR)
```

Updated: if you only need instructors, a simple join will suffice

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,PHONE,ZIP
FROM INSTRUCTOR INNER JOIN STUDENT ON INSTRUCTOR.ZIP = STUDENT.ZIP
```

Comment: `AS derived` is an incorrect syntax (you don't use `AS` when you alias a table in Oracle).

Comment: thanks @PrzemyslawKruglej, I was using TSQL syntax, and have corrected my initial answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest joining the two tables on the zip field.